# How to delete memory of a pointer to pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, free

Using Valgrind, I see that I have a problem while deleting the memory in the following function:

```
Obj1 Obj1::operator*(const Obj1& param) const {
int n = param.GetSize(2);
Obj2** s = new Obj2*[n];
for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    s[i] = new Obj2(*this*param.GetColumn(i+1));
}
Obj1 res = foo(s,n);
for(int i=n-1;i>-1;i--) {
    s[i]->~Obj2();
}
delete[] s;
return res;
```

Valgrind tells me that the leak comes from the line

```
s[i] = new Obj2(*this*param.GetColumn(i+1));
```

I'm not pretty sure if the problem is when I try to free the memory. Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: `s[i]->~Obj2();` doesn't delete the memory. `delete s[i]` does.

Comment: Why are you using manual memory management rather than containers and smart pointers? A naked `delete` is *usually* a code smell in modern C++.

Comment: I think this should be explained in any C++ book. Every `new` must have an according `delete`, simple as that. Whether it's explicit or using smart pointers is irrelevant.

Comment: Calling a destructor and freeing memory are two separate things. `delete` will call the destructor and then free the memory. Calling the destructor will not free the memory.

Comment: @Nikos not to mention that unless you are doing things with *placement new* or similar, explicitly calling a destructor is usually a bug that will often result in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: This looks like a job for `std::vector<Obj2>'.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yeah. Do not manually call destructors unless you know exactly what that means. If you're not 100% sure that you need to, then do not call destructors, they are called automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

> ```
> s[i] = new Obj2(*this*param.GetColumn(i+1));
> ```

you create a dynamic object and assign `s[i]`to point to it.

In order to delete it, you do this:

```
delete s[i];
```

Unless you do that, the allocation will leak.

You must repeat that in a loop for every `i` just like you repeated the allocations. You of course have to do this before you delete `s` itself.

---

> ```
> s[i]->~Obj2();
> ```

Don't do that. Calling the destructor is not appropriate here. `delete` will call the destructor.

---

P.S. Don't use raw owning pointers. Use containers or smart pointers instead. `std::vector` is a standard containers for dynamic arrays.

P.P.S. You should avoid unnecessary dynamic allocation. Your example doesn't demonstrate any need to allocate the pointed objects dynamically. So, in this case you should probably use `std::vector<Obj2>`.